# Eclipse: How to have the code formatter insert tabs after javadoc tags

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I'd like to have:

```
    /**
 * @param from  a point belonging to the map
 * @param to    a point belonging to the map
 * @return      a list of weighted edges on the shortest path from
 *                  {@code from} to {@code to}
 */
```

But eclipse gives me:

```
/**
 * @param from a point belonging to the map
 * @param to a point belonging to the map
 * @return a list of weighted edges on the shortest path from {@code from}
 *         to {@code to}
 */
```

Is there a way to change this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, in eclipse, go to Windows, preferences, Java>Code Style>Formatter, and click on edit. Then look for the comments you want to modify and add a tab.

That said, are you sure you want to do this? Please consider the [guidelines](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html), not to mention that now or in the future, some parsers might fail to find your javadoc, and some programmers might be very annoyed with you ;)

Edit: Oh :/ I'm afraid you're right; I was thinking of Java>CodeStyle>CodeTemplates, which will put whatever you want when a method/class is created. This, however, will not be respected by the autoformatter :(

Comment: +1.  Also other developers are going to reformat your code using their standard settings and change the formatting anyway.

Comment: When I click on "Edit" I get to a window with a few window tabs and settings to configure in the form of checkboxes etc... But I can't find the particular setting to change to achieve the intended result. The closest thing is "indent description of \@param tag" but it doesn't seem to work when \@param and its description are on different lines. Neither does it work with other tags.

As for the guidelines, I am actually getting my cues form them. If you look them trough you'll see they align what follows their tags.

Comment: I should have mentionned I was using Helios. I will download the latest version and see what's up.

Comment: I haven't got more success with Indigo.

Comment: Oh :/ I'm afraid you're right; I was thinking of Java>CodeStyle>CodeTemplates, which will put whatever you want when a method/class is created. This, however, will not be respected by the autoformatter :(

Comment: Since what I asked doesn't seem to be possible, I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Add <br>

```
   
    /**
    * @param from
    *            a point belonging to the map
    * @param to
    *            a point belonging to the map
    * @return a list of weighted edges on the shortest path from<br>
    *         {@code from} to {@code to}
    */
```

Eclipse will include a line-break for each <br>. In Addition, when you generate your JavaDocs with Eclipse it also includes a forced line-break.

Another way to have a fix format is the <pre> </pre> tag.

```
/**
* Some Comments
* 
* <pre>
* Hello
* World
* </pre>
* 
* @param toTest
* @return ...
*/
```

One Problem with <pre> is that you have a forced line-break before the opening <pre> and after the closing </pre> tag, wich means it cannot be used with @return, @param,...

Note: <pre> and <br> are only usable with  JavaDoc-Comments /**. In a normal block-comment /* these two are ignored by eclipse.